# Why does Safari allow a scroll-based video to work as expected, while other browsers don't?

Tags: javascript, video, scroll, controls

I am trying to replicate [this](https://codepen.io/ollieRogers/pen/lfeLc) functionality whereby it is possible to control the video's progression with the mouse scroll. Unusually, the functionality is working flawlessly on *Safari* yet on Firefox, Opera, and Brave it doesn't work - on Chrome the video update seems to be blocked until the entire scroll event has completed, but it does control the video's position. Thus it gives the impression of being very jagged or laggy (and it's thus possible to scroll right past the video on Chrome without it moving at all). I have the feeling that I'm missing something obvious to do with the `requestAnimationFrame` or the `Intersection Observer`. Would some kind soul please have a look and let me know if this is the case, and if so where?

```
<div id="set-height">
  <video width="100%" height="auto" id="v0">
    <source src="Video.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
    <source src="Video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
  </video>
</div>

<script>

  const playbackConst = 150, // lower the number, quicker the animation
        waveVid = document.querySelector('.index-section--scroll-video'),
        vid = document.getElementById('v0');

  let frameNumber = 0,
      myRequest = window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay); 

  function scrollPlay() {
    frameNumber = ((window.innerHeight * 0.7) - vid.getBoundingClientRect().top) / playbackConst; // position of where the animation starts: 100vh - distance to video
    vid.currentTime = frameNumber;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay); // recursive call is necessary for functionality
  }

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      window.cancelAnimationFrame(myRequest); // this was needed as Firefox was eating my CPU up on the site
      return;
    } else {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
      console.log(vid.getBoundingClientRect().top);
    }
  });

  observer.observe(vid);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Although I've found many posts surrounding this functionality, usually citing Apple's product pages as inspiration, none of them seem to run into this particular issue. I did see one [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982520/html5-video-scroll-video ] but I've tested the .mp4 version on Chrome, and it doesn't run any differently - while Safari is smooth. So I'm quite sure it's not related to the quality of the video (going under the assumption that the .mp4 video has better quality than the .webm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419409/html5-video-play-by-scrolling-with-the-mouse-wheel) that contains a key comment by lalengua which I'll just quote here:

> It's important to mention that the video has to be encoded with Keyframes every half or quarter FPS for this effect to work in Firefox and Chrome. And the interval also should be tweaked for each browser as they respond differently. I've had good results using WEBM (VP8) video container for that matter. You could use -g flag with FFMPEG to achieve this: `ffmpeg -i input.mov -g 10 output.webm`

So essentially, with my foot almost in my mouth, all I needed to do was re-encode the video using the `-g` flag, the closer to 1 the smoother the animation. Note that Firefox is still slightly laggier vs Chrome with the same encoding on both browsers, and Safari is still the smoothest with the .mp4 video.

Comment: Life saver!!! Had the exact same problem and this finally worked

Comment: Glad that it was useful for someone else!I barely even remember asking/answering this.